# Отладка с jQuery, ошибки в библиотеке

Tags: jquery, веб-программирование, отладка, webstorm

Начинаю отладку делать своего скрипта (использую IDE WebStorm) и IDE'шка сначала заглядывает 3-4 раза в подключенную библиотеку jquery.1.7.1.min... Затем, когда проверяю содержимое какой-либо переменной через консоль FireBug' (к примеру, `'console.log("%o", virtue)'`), в консоли кроме прочего показываются ошибки библиотеки вида

```
attempt to run compile-and-go script on a cleared scope
    [Прерывать на этой ошибке]

f.event.trigger(a, b, this)

jquery....min.js (строка 1203)
attempt to run compile-and-go script on a cleared scope
    [Прерывать на этой ошибке]

var j, k, l, m, n;

jquery....min.js (строка 2327)
attempt to run compile-and-go script on a cleared scope
error source line:
    [Прерывать на этой ошибке]

var j, k, l, m, n;

jquery....min.js (строка 2327)
attempt to run compile-and-go script on a cleared scope
    [Прерывать на этой ошибке]

var j, k, l, m, n;

jquery....min.js (строка 2327)
```

Кто-нибудь встречался с подобной проблемой? В принципе, это не особо мешает, но... настораживает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А **Web Developer** постоянно показывает ошибки CSS, так же связанные с библиотекой. Так что не обращайте внимания. Хотя, если на все сто процентов отладите библиотеку, то не забудьте поделиться ))

Comment: ххек.. благодарю, успокоили.. =)

Comment: Что-то я не пойму, как приведённые в вопросе ошибки связаны с css.